# Div replacing div but overlaps wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create  a page in which a certain div needs to get visible and replace another div(the other div will be set to invisible).

I can get the first div over the other div by using `position: absolute;`
but the problem now is that the two divs are also in other divs. And if I use `position: absolute;` then these two divs will overlap the other divs. I have made an example please have a look:

```css
#wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 700px;
  }

#list1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#listinList {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

#listOverList {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="list1">
  beginning list 1

  <div id="listinList">
    The first list
  </div>

  <div id="listOverList">
    this must go over the listinlist div
  </div>
</div>
```

My question now is: how can I get the green block (as in the example) to stay inside the yellow wrapper divs.

Comment: Can you please create a visual? I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: See this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/qacLn2nh/1/ , the green block must stay in the yellow block and the yellow block must grow accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hide the `div#listinList`. After this, add the position to `div#listOverList`. I've set the `div#listOverList` to half opacity to show the position over the yellow div.

```css
#wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 700px;
  }

#list1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#listinList {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#listOverList {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="list1">
  beginning list 1
  <div id="listinList">
    The first list
  </div>
  <div id="listOverList">
    this must go over the listinlist div
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for overlapping issue:

```css
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
 #wrapper{
  background-color: red;
  min-height:700px;
 }

 #list1{
  background-color:yellow;
  min-height:200px;
  position:relative;
 }

 #listinList {
               background-color: blue;
               min-height: 170px;
               position: absolute;
               width: 20%;
        }
 #listOverList {
               background-color: green;
               min-height: 170px;
               position: absolute;
               right: 0;
               width: 80%;
        }
```

```html
<body>

<div id= "wrapper">

 top
<div id="list1">
 beginning list 1
 <div id="listinList">
  The first list
 </div>
 <div id="listOverList">
  this must go over the listinlist div
 </div>
</div> 

test
</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but based on your fiddle, have you tried adding the actual positions you want to #listinList and/or #listOverList, e.g.

```
#listOverList {
  ...
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

This should cause the divs to cover its parent completely.